# How to import WordPress featured images with Rsync and MySQL search and replace?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, import, export

Good day!

I have a website and I have to import 2 months of posts. I have used lots of plugins to do so, even WP core functionalities for export/import, but this server it's very poor and I end in a `502 Bad Gateway` everytime. I can export/import all posts, I even have every post with its images, all thanks to [Auto Upload Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/) plugin. What I haven't achieved is put featured images. I have tweaked both `php.ini` and `nginx.conf` several times to permit more script load time, file size, among other things, and ends always in the same error.

That's why I came with a different approach. I synced `/uploads/` directory *(which has every image)* to this new server via Rsync. Now, is there a way via MySQL command, now that I have every image in `/uploads/`, to search inside databasefor the old URL and replace fields with the new URL in order to finally featured images appear in their respective posts?

If that's not the way per se to do it, is there another manual way which wont involve a plugin via the browser I can look into?

Big thanks in advance.

Warm regards.

Comment: Do you try WP CLI - https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/ ?

Comment: That would be great @shvv. Do you know how to do this via WP CLI?